# Show that P is a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

Let $ V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$ - vector space and let $U_1, U_2$ be linear subspaces of $V $ with $V=U_1\oplus U_2$. Futhermore let the linear map $P: V \to V $ be defined by $ P(v)=u_1$ for $v=u_1+u_2 \in V,u_i \in U_i  $.

I need to show that $P$ is a projection and determine $Im(P)$ and $ Ker(P)$.

I don't really know how to do that. However as far as I know $P: V \to V $ is a projection if $P\circ P=P. $

So help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to compute $(P\circ P)(v)$ and $P(v)$? Then you should see something.

Comment: Also what's left after you apply $P$ will be in $Im(P)$ and what gets sent to 0 is in $Ker(f)$. Should be straightforward if you express every vector $v$ as $u_1 + u_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall v = u_1 +u_2 \in V$,

$$(P\circ P)(v) = P(P(v)) = P(u_1) = ?$$

Now to find $Ker P$, remember that $Ker P = \{ v\in V, P(v) = 0 \}$. If you write $v = u_1 + u_2$, how can $P(v) = 0 $?

Comment: Hi. Regarding the projection I would say: $(P\circ P)(v) = P(P(v)) = P(u_1) = u_1 = P(v)$

Comment: @PhysX Right ; and so what does this tell you about $P$ ?

Comment: That $ P∘P=P $ so p is a projection

Comment: @PhysX Correct, now try and find $Ker P$ and you should be done.

Comment: Ok. I would do it like this: $P(v-P(v))=P(v)-P(P(v))=P(v)-P(v)=0 $

Comment: @PhysX This is true ; now if you write $v = u_1 + u_2$, what is $v - P(v)$ ? Then you should be able to find $Ker P$ without me telling you every step :-)

Comment: Ok. This is my last comment :D. With $v=u_1+u_2$ we have $u_1=P(v) \in Im(P)$ and $u_2=v-P(v) \in Ker(P)$. That means: $V=Ker(P)+Im(P)$.